# Manipulating individual bytes in assembly

Tags: assembly

I am learning assembly and I am trying to write to individual `bytes` in a `bytes32` array. I have the following code:

```
contract TestAssembly {}
    function test(
        uint8 _count
    ) public {
        bytes32 bytesTest;
        assembly { 
            for { let i := 0} lt(i, _count) { i := add(i, 1) } { 
                mstore(add(bytesTest, i), 0x33)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping that this code would iterate through each bytes in `bytesTest`, and replace each by `0x33`, however `bytesTest` doesn't seem be modified.

Comment: `bytes1` through `bytes32` local variables are stored on the stack, not in memory, so they cannot be manipulated with `mstore`. `bytes memory bytesTest;` is stored in memory.

Comment: @Jesbus I see, so knowing that, how would one go about doing this bytes wise operations

Comment: You can use bitwise ops like `SHL`, `SHR`, `OR`, `AND`, `BYTE` to manipulate a value on the stack byte by byte. You don't need assembly to do that. Nota bene: `mstore` writes 32 bytes of data to memory. `mstore8` can be used to only write a single byte.

Comment: thanks for mentioning this @Jesbus, I might actually skip assembly for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up on @Jesbus comment, here is a commented example achieving what you want :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestAssembly {
    function test(uint8 _count) public pure returns (bytes memory) {

        // Declares the array in memory
        bytes memory bytesTest = new bytes(10);

        // Protect against buffer overflow
        require(_count <= 10, "not enough bytes in the array");

        assembly {

            // Skip the first 32 bytes reserved for the length of the memory array
            let offset := add(bytesTest, 0x20)

            // Loop _count times over the array
            for { let i := 0} lt(i, _count) { i := add(i, 1) } { 
                // Make use of mstore8 (1 byte) instead of mstore (32 bytes)
                mstore8(add(offset, i), 0x33)
            }
        }

        return bytesTest;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** :

I'm adding an example relying on array literals where there is no length prefix and using bytes32.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestAssembly {
    function test(uint8 _count) public pure returns (bytes32) {

        // Declares the byte32 array in memory : this is an array literal -> there is no length prefix
        bytes32[1] memory bytesTest = [bytes32(0)];

        // Protect against buffer overflow
        require(_count <= 32, "not enough bytes in the array");

        assembly {
            // Loop _count times over the array
            for { let i := 0} lt(i, _count) { i := add(i, 1) } { 
                // Make use of mstore8 (1 byte) instead of mstore (32 bytes)
                mstore8(add(bytesTest, i), 0x33)
            }
        }

        return bytesTest[0];
    }
}
```

Plus a third example not relying on solidity arrays but directly allocating / computing in memory through assembly.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestAssembly {
    function test(uint8 _count) public pure returns (bytes32) {

        bytes32 result;

        // Protect against buffer overflow
        require(_count <= 32, "not enough bytes in the array");

        assembly {
            
            // Allocate 32 bytes from the free memory pointer
            let buffer := mload(0x40)

            // Increase the free memory pointer to account for our buffer
            mstore(0x40, add(buffer, 0x20))

            // Loop _count times over the array
            for { let i := 0} lt(i, _count) { i := add(i, 1) } { 
                // Make use of mstore8 (1 byte) instead of mstore (32 bytes)
                mstore8(add(buffer, i), 0x33)
            }

            result := mload(buffer)

            // Decrease the free memory pointer to account for our buffer
            mstore(0x40, sub(buffer, 0x20))
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So is it not possible to manipulate a bytes32, byte by byte ? I would rather store bytes32 as then I dont have the overhead of storing the array size

Comment: Also why bytes(10), couldn't it be 32?

Comment: 10 was completely arbitrary.  I'll add an example with a bytes32 array literal (that doesn't require any length prefix).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's starting to make sense now. I am leaving the question open until I am done with the code in case I find anything useful to add.